# Using JSON square bracket notation within Angular directives to access values

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON object that contains namespaces in some of its keys in the form of `namespace:key`. Because of this, I need to use the square bracket notation instead of the dot notation to access its value.

I am trying to use some angular directives/filters to work with the data, in this example I will be using `filter`, but the issue seems transversal to the use of bracket notation within the directives as well.

Here's my example:

**ng-repeat with filter in HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{properties['namespace:status']}">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**$scope.items content:**

```
{
  "properties":{
    "namespace:status":"A",
    "name":"Potato",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
},
{
  "properties":{
    "namespace:status":"B",
    "name":"Carrot",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
},
{
  "properties":{
    // Note that it doesn't contain the namespace attribute
    "name":"Bean",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

**Expected rendered HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Potato</li>
  <li>Carrot</li>
</ul>
```

**Actual outcome**

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '[' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column X of the expression [items | filter:{properties['namespace:status']}] starting at [['namespace:status']}].
```

directing me to a syntax error.

My issue is that the same expression `{{properties['namespace:status']}}` does fits the syntax in templates, so I'm not sure I am doing something wrong, or if the directives simply can't handle the bracket notation.

If its the latter, any suggestions on how I could approach this without rewriting the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify an object key like that

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{prop: properties['namespace:status']}">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here you can check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BslpA

But you should know that angularjs can not filter by array of object properties, it can be only array.

Comment: that was it. regarding the array of object properties thing, I might end up to use a different directive